# Working with poorly written code, cannot meet a hard deadline in probation period

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, probation, deadlines

I joined my current company recently, and I am on probation. The code I have inherited is brittle and has performance issues. I am not familiar with the system yet, but my manager told me to refactor this code, document it and set a hard deadline to do the first release by end of the next month.

I started working on this project last week. For a small refactoring in a simple component, I had to do many changes at various places. I fear that if I do a major refactoring, I would end up coding the project from scratch, and I will miss the deadline for sure. If I avoid doing this, the project is doomed to fail as code can break in multiple ways.

My manager made me sign a document that says I am supposed to complete all the tasks. Being nervous and confused, I signed the document. Now I fear that if I cannot complete the tasks, the whole blame will be on me. The project has already failed three times, and my manager is damned serious to make it work this time.

How should I professionally communicate to my manager that the issues with the code may cause me to miss the deadline?

Comment: He's not serious about or he wouldn't be doing it like that

Comment: @john doe I have edited your question description to include a question that I infer to be your actual goal. Your original question of "what should I do?" is too open-ended, and not a good fit for this site. If you do not agree with this, please let me know or [edit] the question to include a practically answerable question we can try to help with. The linked duplicate is probably helpful in your situation as well.

Comment: I don't think the duplicate is a real duplicate. This is a deadline from management versus a self-given deadline, which alone makes a lot of difference.

Comment: @Erik That is an excellent point, I seem to have overlooked that. It is not clear though if the OP was consulted before the manager set the deadline. There is also a possibility of miscommunication here. The manager saying, "we would like to have the first release by next month" doesn't necessarily imply it is a "hard" deadline, just that the management wishes for it. That seems to be one more reason why this is not a duplicate, I will retract my duplicate vote.

Comment: I would recommend documenting broken parts, challenges as well. You need to account for the time you spend. Definitely need to invest personal time to get some more progress if you want to show grit. On the other hand, this looks like weak leadership skill and micromanagement from top to down, by time, with growing issues it gets worse in my experience. Use that place as a stepping stone to better job and leave it in your rearview mirror as soon as possible.

Comment: @sdkks You make some good points, might want to consider fleshing it out into a full fledged answer.

Comment: It is not clear what problem you are trying to solve. Is the code working correctly but has performance issues? Why is refactoring the solution? Is the code buggy and hard to maintain? Is it possible to fix the bugs without refactoring EVERYTHING as the first step? I also don't understand what was the point of signing a doc since you are on probation and your manager would decide if you would continue anyway. I think your post omits important information

Comment: @smith I think you didn't read the question clearly, there is a fresher who don't know what is a SRP or DRY and he has written a full system which is supposed to be released next month. Signing the doc was not my choice it was the choice of my manager.

Comment: @johndoe: the code has performance issues, I guess some bugs and needs to be released fast. My questions to you are 1) can you fix the performance issues and bugs and get it working correctly without refactoring everything within the dealine? 2) do you have any reason not to present that to your manager as a solution? I mean your manager wants it out the door. Surely refactoring is not what he cares most

Comment: Btw I've just bumped into this. Psychological safety at work, some good points: https://blog.intercom.com/psychological-safety/

Comment: You don't eat a foot long sub, all at once, take care of problems you can solve by a deadline.  Iterate from that point

Comment: Earnest, well-meaning people often make the mistake of committing to projects with unrealistic deadlines. They sense the urgency of the request and then attempt a heroic effort to meet the deadline, going into the project with no idea of the problems and obstacles they're going to encounter. Such plots would make good fodder for a game-show on TV, but it leads to failure and disappointment in real projects. Managers who demand and accept such commitments are guilty too and deserve some pain, but sadly, hard-workers like the OP are the ones who really get hurt. Take it as a learning experience.

Comment: What if the doc is a ruse for you to work off-hours?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Managers can say all they want, they are generally not very good at calculating deadlines. The only people who can really tell how much work something is, are the people who know how to actually do it and who are familiar enough with it to make the estimations.

What you'll want to do is gather all the information you have on the project and make your *own* estimations on how big of a project this is. You've already done part of the work, so make sure you include that, as well as your worst predictions for how messy the code is and how much of it you'll have to rewrite.

Then call a meeting with your manager, show them your data and your predictions for how big this project really is and ask them what they want done. Tell them how much you *can* do before the deadline, tell them how long it would take you to do everything, and give them some suggestions on how the work might be done better (for example, getting more people working on it, skipping certain segments that are very hard but don't help much, buying some new technology that handles part of the problem, whatever you can think of)

At the end you want to present them with the facts and try and work *with* the manager to come up with something that is both useful to the business **and** realistic.

If your manager doesn't want to hear it and just keeps you to the deadline you signed up for, then they are denying reality. And no matter how much you'd like to deny reality, it's going to win in the end. If you think getting everything done is completely unreasonable and your manager insists you have to do it, then the only realistic thing left for you to do, is spend your time looking for a new job, because you can't please someone who ignores the facts.

(Also, if your manager asks why you signed the document, be honest. Tell them you were nervous and didn't think it through, and that you regret signing it because you now feel it wasn't doable. It's just a document. Sane people understand that writing it down doesn't make it real, and that you'll have to change the document if your goal is to get the work done.)

Comment: All good advice.  Also, for your own sanity and security, make sure you're writing tests as you go, or else the refactor may wind up breaking things in unexpected ways despite your best efforts.

Comment: @Paul in theory it sounds good but writing tests for a nearly finished project seems a suicidal idea unless I am given time to re-write the project from scratch.

Comment: @johnDoe i mean write a test for anything you're going to change before you change it. I'd argue that not doing that is suicide

Comment: @Erik: the kind of manager you describe surely has no interest on a refactoring per se. Surely just wants the product out the door. I think there is something missing from the post.

Comment: @smith it's the engineers job to manage the quality of the code, not the managers'. If the engineer cannot find a way to make the code work reliably and efficiently without refactoring, than they'll have to explain that to the manager.

Comment: I read the post saying quite clearly "refactor and document".

Answer (score 8):

> My manager made me sign a document that says I am supposed to complete
>   all the tasks. Being nervous and confused, I signed the document. Now
>   I fear that if I cannot complete the tasks, the whole blame will be on
>   me. The project has already failed three times, and my manager is
>   damned serious to make it work this time.
>
> How should I professionally communicate to my manager that the issues
>   with the code may cause me to miss the deadline?

Tell your manager **now** that your examination of the code leads you to believe you will not be able to meet the deadline and why, but that you'll do your best anyway. Also, tell them **now** what your approach will be and how long *you* think it will take to complete the task, and that you'll update your estimate as you learn more.

It's silly that your manager believes a signed document will make any difference. But you owe the company your best efforts and your best estimate. And perhaps your manager will come to his senses and accept reality, perhaps not.

Note that in the end it may not matter. You may miss the deadline on the signed document, and your employer may choose to let you go and start all over with another new hire. But you should give it your best shot anyway.

Comment: Looks like the manager wasn't interested in an estimate. And I'm not sure what this manager is thinking, but to give a reasonable estimate for the task "refactor and document this code", you have to spend a good amount of time first to see what the quality of the code is.